# How to allocate struct pointer inside a struct dynamically?

Tags: c, struct

I currently have a struct Struct1 which has a pointer to Struct2 that gets allocated multiple times based on some conditions in the code. I tried to allocate it `test->Struct2Pair[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct2));`this way but it seems to fail. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

```
struct Struct2 {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Struct1 {
    struct Struct2 *Struct2Pair;
    int val;
};

int main()
{

    struct Struct1 *test = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct1));
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        test->Struct2Pair[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Struct2Pair` is uninitialized -- you cannot just start assigning values to it as if it's a valid array.  At the very least, you would need `test->Struct2Pair = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct Struct2));` which allocates memory for 5 elements of type `struct Struct2`.  But if you're going to just hard-code an array, why not simply define it as `struct Struct2 Struct2Pair[5];` in the first place?

Comment: @paddy like I said that 5 is just an example. That number is variable based on some inputs and some computation. I just want to know how to malloc test->Struct2Pair each time some condition is satisfied. It can be 1... it can be 100. I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: @JaneDoe: When you do `test->Struct2Pair[i]`, you are trying to get access memory location of `Struct2Pair` which doesn't point to anything meaningful yet.

Comment: If you need to know how many items the array holds, then you need to store that value somewhere (an extra variable in `Struct1` perhaps).  Otherwise you have no way of knowing if the array is large enough (if you plan to resize it later with `realloc` or whatever).  I stand by my comment about how to allocate the array using `malloc`.  You're doing it wrong.  The only modification here is to use a variable size instead of hard-coding the `5`, and store the value somewhere.

Comment: It is runtime and not known while allocation of Struct2Pair. It keeps getting allocated one by one if certain conditions are satisfied. Would your solution still work in that case?

Comment: Yes.  It's your responsibility to keep track of the count and allocations accordingly.  If you don't know the number of items in the beginning, you could set the count to zero and the pointer to NULL.  Then any time you need to add an element, increase the count and call `realloc`.  It's not the most efficient solution, but it will work and be the easiest for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks @paddy

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `Struct2Pair` to point 5 consecutive memory object of type `Struct2` you must allocate a `5*sizeof(Struct2)`. so in latter part of code you can access it as an array of size 5.

You must do `null` check for the return value of `malloc`.

```
    struct Struct1 *test = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct1));

        //   |-----change is here and here--------------|
        //   v                                          v
        test->Struct2Pair = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct2) * 5);
    
    //access can be as follows for all the index from 0  to 4
    test->Struct2Pair[2].x = 10;
    test->Struct2Pair[2].y = 20;
```

For better visualization refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113088/4139593) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60262738/4139593).

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are having is located within the `for` loop and the number of available `Struct2`s in the `test->Struct2Pair` array.

You hadn't allocated any space for `test->Struct2Pair` before placing `Struct2`s into it

```
test->Struct2Pair[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct2));
```

Then loop through more indexes then are available for the `test->Struct2Pair` array

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
```

You may consider adding another variable to store the size of the `test->Struct2Pair` array:

```
int size = 5;
struct Struct1 *test = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct1));
test->Struct2Pair = malloc(size * sizeof(struct Struct2));
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    test->Struct2Pair[i].x = 0;
    test->Struct2Pair[i].y = 0;
}
```

Reference on `malloc`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc

Comment: That is incorrect. `Struct2Pair` is uninitialized. Accessing it would be UB.

Comment: Answer, acquire, and adapt. I eyeballed the question then adjusted the answer. Just opened a shell and tested the adjusted code and it compiles and runs.

Comment: No problem @JaneDoe. I noticed realloc was mentioned without any reference. In case you do choose that route here's a general example of it's usage: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: And here's another reference for dynamic memory management: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx11.html

Comment: I did end up going the realloc way. 

Did `test->Struct2Pair = calloc(0, sizeof(struct Struct2));` first and then
`test->Struct2Pair = realloc(test->Struct2Pair, (i+1) * sizeof(struct Struct2));`

This seemed to solve my issues!